# RavenDB Silverlight error Debugging resource strings are unavailable

Tags: silverlight, domain-driven-design, ravendb

RavenDB has started throwing this error when i attempt to edit a document via the ravenDB silverlight interface.  it appears machine specific at the moment, any idea whats causing this error?

> [Arg_TargetInvocationException] Arguments:  Debugging resource strings
>   are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60531.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_TargetInvocationException
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.*InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
>   at Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.InitializeComponent(Object element)
>
>   at Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.<.cctor>b*_3(Type viewType)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.<.cctor>b_*9(Type modelType,
>   DependencyObject displayLocation, Object context)    at
>   Raven.Studio.StudioViewLocator.LocateForModelType(Type modelType,
>   DependencyObject viewLocation, Object context, Func`4 original)    at
>   Raven.Studio.AppBootstrapper.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ConfigureConventions>b__9(Type
>   t, DependencyObject v, Object c)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.<.cctor>b__a(Object model, DependencyObject
>   displayLocation, Object context)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.View.OnModelChanged(DependencyObject targetLocation,
>   DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty
>   property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry,
>   ValueOperation operation)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty
>   dp)    at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
>
>   at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourcePropertyChanged(PropertyPathListener
>   sender, PropertyPathChangedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.RaisePropertyPathStepChanged(PropertyPathStep
>   source)    at
>   System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.RaisePropertyPathStepChanged(PropertyListener
>   source)    at
>   System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.SourcePropertyChanged(Object
>   sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.WeakPropertyChangedListener.PropertyChangedCallback(Object
>   sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase.RaisePropertyChangedEventCore(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase.<>c__DisplayClass3.<NotifyOfPropertyChange>b__2()
>   at
>   Caliburn.Micro.Execute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InitializeWithDispatcher>b__0(Action
>   action)    at Caliburn.Micro.Execute.OnUIThread(Action action)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase.NotifyOfPropertyChange(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.ConductorBaseWithActiveItem`1.ChangeActiveItem(T
>   newItem, Boolean closePrevious)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.Conductor`1.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ActivateItem>b__0(Boolean
>   canClose, IEnumerable`1 items)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.DefaultCloseStrategy`1.Evaluate(Boolean result,
>   IEnumerator`1 enumerator, Action`2 callback)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.DefaultCloseStrategy`1.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b_*0(Boolean
>   canClose)    at Caliburn.Micro.Screen.CanClose(Action`1 callback)
>
>   at Caliburn.Micro.DefaultCloseStrategy`1.Evaluate(Boolean result,
>   IEnumerator`1 enumerator, Action`2 callback)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.DefaultCloseStrategy`1.Execute(IEnumerable`1 toClose,
>   Action`2 callback)    at Caliburn.Micro.Conductor`1.ActivateItem(T
>   item)    at
>   Raven.Studio.Features.Database.DatabaseExplorer.ActivateItem(Object
>   item)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.ConductorBase`1.Caliburn.Micro.IConductor.ActivateItem(Object
>   item)    at
>   Raven.Studio.Framework.Extensions.ScreenExtensions.TrackNavigationTo[T](T
>   conductor, IScreen newScreen, IEventAggregator events, Action
>   setContext)    at
>   Raven.Studio.Features.Database.DatabaseExplorer.Caliburn.Micro.IHandle<Raven.Studio.Messages.DatabaseScreenRequested>.Handle(DatabaseScreenRequested
>   message)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator.<>c__DisplayClasse`1.b*_c()
>   at
>   Caliburn.Micro.Execute.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(Action
>   action)    at Caliburn.Micro.Execute.OnUIThread(Action action)    at
>   Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator.Publish[TMessage](TMessage message)
>   at Raven.Studio.Commands.EditDocument.Execute(DocumentViewModel
>   document)

thanks

Comment: this is all i get.. when using the UI.. click EDIT on the document in ravendb and i get this error.  I'm still able to write to the document store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build 531 fixed this issue.
[RavenDB google group](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/b7888a3ae7223988)

Answer (score 0):

seems like its a DD/MM issue thats hitting everyone today, reset the clock PC to last week (06/Nov/2011) and it works..oops will be expecting a fix asap :)
https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/62e55f335ffd7fdd